# Page not working in firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

For some reason the webpage I am working on doesn't seem to be working on firefox or ie correctly.  It works fine in chrome, but in firefox and ie the main content area is pushed over to the right and the right sidebar drops down because of this.  I can't figure out why this is happening.  Can someone help?

My URL is : http://dev.internationalservicescenter.org/product/blue-t-shirt

Comment: It'd be better if you included an image of what's going on, that way we're not dependent upon your site going down. Also, show us your CSS code, and why it's not behaving as you think it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your menu is wrapping.  You can make sure your `.navigationArea` div is all the way to the left by applying the rule `clear: left;` to it.

Comment: Thanks, I new the nav was screwed up, but didn't realize it was messing the rest of the page up as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is to do with your div with id=nav.

Give it a width of 100% and work from there.
Also set the padding-right of the elements in the nav to be 15px not 20px.

I'm looking via Chrome